# Notion API Get database : guest limitations?

Tags: postman, notion-api

I'm using Notion API to display a collection of photos in a react app (using graphql).

For that I've created a simple database in notion, with basic information (title, status, tags, category, photo url).

Everything is fine with my test set of data. I can see it in my react app, in graphql (appolo studio), in Postman and in Notion

But I cannot not access new data recently contributed.
Not in my react app and even not in Postman (I can see only the intial set of data).

- I've checked the authorizations, everything is clean.
- These new data are available in Notion (I can see and edit them).
- When I (owner of the project) add a new row, the data is available in postman and in the app.
- If I copy and paste a row contributed by my friend, the data is not available.

The additional data was provided by a friend of mine, with a guest status in the project.

So my only finding so far is that there is a limitation on data provided by a guest, even if it seems a bit weird.

Are there any known limitations on Notion API due to the status of the contributor ?
Or are there other limitations that could explain these partial results ?

Comment: Some additional information. 
Not sure the guest status is the causeis. When another guest add data, it  works (but copy paste of the additional data do not).
When trying to display additional data in a new page, Notion displays "importing" without any result (even if those data are visible on the database view)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.